# Why are these words lacking picturesque meaning?

Tags: semantics, formal-semantics

I was thinking about words that would be as hard as possible to mime (for example, in a game like Charades).

I thought of some words - “the”, “of”, “as”, “a”, “if”, “general”, “abstract”.

Consider how much easier it is to like words like “cat”, “drive”, “Mr. Bean”, or “propulsion”.

I would like a deep theory about what’s going on here.

I think anything with a definite form - a way it moves, looks, or behaves, or a single quality it has, is easy to mime simply by mimicking it.

There is a class of words which are easy to demonstrate if you can gesturally refer to them, but almost impossible if you cannot. “Orange” or “three” can be pointed at or shown with the fingers, but in a way, you are replacing using a word with a physical example of the concept itself. For the words in the paragraph above, it would be like “miming” the word “cat” by pointing to your pet cat as it walked by.

The list of “difficult to mime” words have (almost) no qualitative characteristics to try to portray. We might consider words like “the” and “of” are not “predicates” in “logical form”, like “exists x such that CAT(x)”. If language builds propositions out of concepts, we can say “the” and “as” aren’t concepts, that may be why they are so hard to mime. It would lead to the question of what all words that are not concepts are.

I wonder if the hypothesis would not hold up. There are some words that seem abstract, like the preposition “to”. But it is easy to “map” it to a familiar idea: towards - going - by moving your handing forward. “Might” is a modal auxiliary, but you can associate it with ambivalence, and act out indecisiveness.

Also, “general” and “abstract” are “predicative”, and they technically are “conceptual”. Yet, they are featureless. In all seriousness, I feel the best you could do would be an odd interpretive dance to get a very general sense across - and it honestly could work.

But, why? My best guess for now is they are ideas defined more as a relation between things than a thing itself; sort of a “meta”-concept.

Comment: “the”, “of”, “as”, “a”, and “if” are all part of the machinery, without any lexical meaning. Since lexical meaning is what miming is about, these words just don't show up in charades, except with conventions like "sounds like".

Comment: And completely abstract nouns like _general_ and _abstract_ itself require long definitions to understand, and again, miming is not very good for that. About as good as English orthography is in conveying all of a real conversation in English.

Answer (score 1):

As best I can make out, your question is about the chain of experiences relating word meaning to their referent. Nouns tend to be easiest, especially one that refer to concrete everyday objects – you can point to a dog and say "sqʷəbay" and the listener will pretty quickly get the association between word and referent. You may have to call on some metalinguistic tools like "not" so that you can teach the difference between sheep and goat, dog and cat, or dog and coyote. Nouns like "mammal" or "fruit" are higher-order abstractions that group together perceptually-easy words like "dog, cat, rat..." or "apple, lemon, pear...". Ostensive ("pointing") definitions are at the bottom of the hierarchy. Instances of "mammal" and "fruit" can be experienced (that is, you can be shown a mammal, and another mammal, and from that you can start to learn what a mammal is): but you can also learn what a "mammal" is by learning the specific names of things under the roof "mammal".

Words like "the, of, as, a, if" cannot be explained by pointing. Actually, "of" cannot be explained, you just devise the best list of examples that you can. But since you've already defined very many more-concrete words, such as things that you directly experience, or things that group together the things that you directly experience, you can take a stab at explaining the meaning of "the" in terms of words that are more-closely related to direct experience. As an exercise, you could try to give an simple explanation of what "the" does (means), to see what other concepts the definition of "the" depends on, and ultimately reduce all of those ideas to something that can be directly experienced.